# How to use different flutter flavors with Codemagic?

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, codemagic

I wonder how to set up different flavors in Codemagic?

```
enum Environment {
  dev,
  stage,
  prod,
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is than in documentation of Codemagic there are no hints how to set up flutter with different favors.

Comment: @evgen you can find it here https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-quick-start/codemagic-sample-projects/#flutter-samples

Answer (score 0):

you can find sample project how to build Flutter app with flavors here https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/codemagic-sample-projects/tree/main/flutter/flutter-flavors-demo-project